# c++11 - private constructor still callable

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, new-operator, private

I have somewhat the following definition of a class in `MainLoop.h`:

```
class MainLoop {
    private:
        static const MainLoop     &s_instance;
    public:
        static inline const MainLoop &Instance(void) 
            { return s_instance; }
  
    private:
        MainLoop(MainLoop &mp);
        MainLoop(MainLoop &&mp);
        MainLoop &operator=(MainLoop &mp);
        MainLoop &operator=(MainLoop &&mp);
        ~MainLoop();
        MainLoop()
            { printf("Main Loop is created\n"); };
};
```

And somewhat like that in the source file `MainLoop.cpp`:

```
#include "MainLoop.h"

const MainLoop &MainLoop::s_instance( (MainLoop()) );
```

This code does not compile because the `dtor` is private in the scope, but if I change it to the whimsical

```
#include "MainLoop.h"

const MainLoop &MainLoop::s_instance( *( new MainLoop()) );
```

it then compiles without saying a word and the class is created before the `main` function is called.

I have to questions:

1. Why the `ctor` is called in the second variant while being private?
2. Why the `dtor`'s access rights are different in the first variant?

Comment: Since you call the constructor from within the class itself, both options should compile. Looks like a GCC bug to me, Clang and MSVC accept it. The second option never calls the destructor.

Comment: Personally, I would just move the `s_instance` variable inside of `Instance()`, eg: `static const MainLoop& Instance() { static const MainLoop s_instance; return s_instance; }`

Comment: @HolyBlackCat - could you elaborate a little bit on your comment? It's a bit opaque for me how both options work inside of the class? I mean, the staic variable is defined and inited in the `cpp` file and the class is created in the file(global) scope, at least that is what I though was going on. The only thing that I can relate to this possibility is `in-class brace-or-equal initializer`, but ,once again, how it could be `in-class`?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - it seems to me like a great alternative, thanks! But now it is not exactly clear for me how the calling code would get the `s_instance` provided copy, move and assignment operators are put private and, moreover, undefined. It definitely does compile and run, but why? It it because return value optimization?


Btw, will it create a destructor for `s_instance` at the end of the program?

Comment: Even though it outside of the class body, it still counts as being "in" the class.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat could you please clarify what exactly makes it being "in" the class?

Comment: The fact that it's a member of the class. There isn't much theory to be explained here.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I mean, yeah, but isn't it only allowed to access `private` members from the class' scope?

Comment: Apparently not.

Comment: @AntonTretyakov `Instance()` returns a *reference* to `s_instance`. There is no copy or move performed, so those constructors/assignments can be private/deleted. And since the variable is defined inside a method of the same class, the default constructor and destructor can be private. And yes, the local `static` variable will be destroyed at program exit. Another benefit of this approach is that the local variable won't be created until the 1st time `Instance()` is called at runtime, whereas if you declare the variable as a static member of the class then it is created at program startup.

Comment: @RemyLebeau of course! Thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Welp, I haven't found the exact wording of the standard, but [this page](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.1.0?topic=members-static-data) of IBM site says that:

> The initializer for a static data member is in the scope of the class declaring the member

So, it seems like the scope of the class is extended.

[This page](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/scope) at cppreference.com says that class scope is extended to "*in-class brace-or-equal initializers*", so probably this is it.